# Need to execute operations sequentially with Akka

Tags: akka, actor

I have an actor which is orchestrating database updates. I need to ensure that each operation gets executed only after the previous one gets completed. 
This because operation B will reuse the result of operation A.

Here the code I wrote for the actor.

```
class DbUpdateActor(databaseOperations: DBProvider) extends Actor {

  implicit val ec:ExecutionContext = context.system.dispatcher

  def receive: Receive = {

    case newInfo : UpdateDb =>

      val future = Future {
            // gets the current situation from DB 
            val status = databaseOperations.getSituation()
            // do db update
            databaseOperations.save(something)
      }

      future onComplete {
        case Success(result: List[Int]) =>
            //
        case Failure(err: Throwable) =>
            //
      }
  }
}
```

The code works fine for a single operation. If I fire two updates then the second one is executed asynchronously so it gets started before the first one has completed.

I was reading about different types of mailbox, not sure if having a different one would help.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can explore would be to remove that `Future` and allow that blocking db code to be run within the actor.  Then, use a separate dispatcher (perhaps a PinnedDispatcher) to fire-wall this blocking code off from the main actor system's dispatcher, giving it its own thread to run on.  By blocking in the body and removing that `Future`, you will ensure proper sequential execution of the actor's mailbox.  A rough sketch of the changes to make that work are as follows:

```
object DbUpdateActor{
  def props(databaseOperations:DBProvider) =
    Props(classOf[DbUpdateActor], databaseOperations).
      withDispatcher("db-update-dispatcher")
}

class DbUpdateActor(databaseOperations: DBProvider) extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {

    case newInfo : UpdateDb =>
      val status = databaseOperations.getSituation()
      databaseOperations.save(something)
  }
}
```

Then, as long as you had the following dispatcher configured in your actor system config:

```
db-update-dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  type = PinnedDispatcher
}
```

And you started up the db update actor like so:

```
val updater = system.actorOf(DbUpdateActor.props(databaseOperations))
```

Then you should be all set setting this actor up to run that blocking code in a way that won't negatively affect the throughput of the main dispatcher.

Comment: that worked very well. I was expecting the Future block to keep the actor busy and to proceed to the next message only after the future block to be completed. What am I missing?

Comment: Callbacks that you register on a `Future` (like `onComplete` in your case) process asynchronously, more than likely on a completely different thread.  That means that code execution on the current thread continues on.  In your case, there is no more code after that `Future`, so the actor completes the handling of that message and moves onto the next one.  You need to be careful mixing `Future`s and actors because of this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: start operation A in a child; when the child is complete it sends the parent a message saying it completed. Then you can start operation B, either in the existing or a new child.